# perl cgi session info not returned on new page

Tags: perl, cgi, session-management

i am trying to use cgi::session, but no luck yet. index.html has form which gets user credentials, matches them with mysql databases values, and if right, then sets a session otherwise shows login.html

```
# create a new session  
my $session = CGI::Session->new() or die CGI::Session->errstr;  
print $session->header();   
#setting session to expire in 1 hour                              
$session->expire("+1h");
$session->flush();
#further in page
# logout option 
print "<a href='logout.cgi'>logout </a></br>";
# check option  
print "<a href='check.cgi'>check page</a>"
```

this page gives output properly, it gnerates session id, but when i click on check page link, it doesn't show me session info and i always get "no session" message.

```
# cgi page
my $cgi = CGI->new;
#print $cgi->header();
print $cgi->start_html();
print $cgi->p("hello");
print $cgi->cookie('CGISESSID');
# load session info
my $session = CGI::Session->load() or die CGI::Session->errstr;
print $session->header();
if ($session->is_empty) 
{
    print $cgi->p("no session");
    }
    else
    {
    print $cgi->p("<b>session data loaded</b>");
    print $session->name;   
    print $session->id;
    print $session->is_expired;
    }
print $cgi->end_html();
```

and this is code in logout.cgi

```
# Delete the session for good:
my $session = CGI::Session->load() or die CGI::Session->errstr;
$session->delete();
$session->flush();
print $session->header(-location=>'http://login.com');
```

what am i doing wrong?

How come I am getting two different results.
1. IE9 and Firefox showed started session id, but when clicked on check.cgi IE showed different session id, and Firefox showed none.
2. Both browsers returned, `session->is_empty` as true. when check.cgi ran.

When I run scripts from command line mode, it doesn't shows any errors. (returns syntax ok) I am trying to retreive session info from cookie and param but no luck yet.

note: don't want to use frameworks like dancer, catalyst etc, for keeping it simple purpose